# How to publish audio from android microphone to Red5 server app?

Tags: android, red5, rtmp

How can i publish audio from android microphone to Red5 server app oflademo to create flv file there?

Answer (score 0):

You can start for example by build a Java RTMPClient using the current trunk version:
http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/client/trunk/

There is also a Blog article from a red5 dev about it:
http://gregoire.org/2012/01/17/android-market/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian!! But is there any sample code available for android ?? Means how to convert audio from mic to vlc and then to push on RTMP or Red5 server??

Comment: I don't think you would grab it using vlc. You should try to access the mic using Java, and then use the RTMPClient to write the packets to the red5 server as FLV stream. FFMPEG can also write as RTMP stream.